# Database multitenancy and new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I've implemented database multitenancy in my spring-boot application using `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` and `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`

I have one static instance of connection to db and one dynamic by multitentant,
everything worked fine until I get forced to use multithreating.

New Thread seems to loose information about that dynamic connection (the static is fine), so I have a question, is there any posibility to pass the connection information to the new thread to be able use JPA Repository, as I can do normally?

Thanks for answers and advises

Comment: I have the same issue, would be great if someone has a solution and can reply. thanks

Comment: If multi-tenancy fails with multi-threading, it's a bug really. But not sure if that's the case. I am using ExecutorService and it seems to lose the  information on the current tenant identifier

Answer (score 2):

What we need is to pass ***tenant id*** from current thread to newly created thread to work in multi tenancy mode. For this, we have to maintain TenantContext as follows:

```
public class TenantContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Tenant> tenantHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static Tenant getTenant() {
        Tenant tenant = tenantHolder.get();
        return Objects.isNull(tenant) ? Tenant.DEFAULT : tenant;
    }

    public static void setTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        tenantHolder.set(tenant);
    }

    public static void clearTenant() {
        tenantHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

**Tenant** is the enum which holds all Tenant Ids. When we first resolve tenant before creating new thread, we have to set it to **TenantContext**.

Now, we have to write new custom thread class.

```
public class TenantAwareThread extends Thread {
    private Tenant tenant = null;

    public TenantAwareThread(Runnable target) {
        super(target);
        this.tenant = TenantContext.getTenant();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        TenantContext.setTenant(this.tenant);
        super.run();
        TenantContext.clearTenant();
    }
}
```

Finally, we can create thread as follows:

```
new TenantAwareThread(() -> {
    //do operation
}).start();
```

New thread will get tenant ID automatically and properly access the right tenant's database.

Comment: Related blog: https://medium.com/@arifng/best-way-to-pass-tenant-id-to-new-thread-in-java-9e658032387f?source=friends_link&sk=510952927fafededdf62fcc006ad5892

Answer (score 1):

Please use a TenantContext as explained here - https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation

Every time a new thread is invoked, make sure the context is reset because a new thread would lose the current tenant's identifier information.

Answer (score 0):

Either pass tenant id / information in the request as part of the URL or in a Header and have a filter to set it to the ThreadLocal via a Tenant Holder / Context.

I blogged about this at [Multi-tenant applications using Spring Boot, JPA, Hibernate and Postgres](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/01/17/Multitenant-applications-using-Spring-Boot-JPA-Hibernate-and-Postgres.html)

I will soon blog about how to pass tenant data via kind of a TenantStore to prevent directly messing with ThreadLocal with the support to inject TenantStore in Services, Resources, ...

Comment: I was actually using your blog as an example on implementation of multitenancy, but the problem with no information about actual tenant shows on new thread.

Comment: I didn't get "no information about actual tenant shows on new thread." Could you please elaborate? If I remember correctly, if no tenant id is passed it resolves to "tenant_1" in the ResolverImpl class